# Templates and std::numeric_limits

Tags: c++, templates, numeric-limits

I have a class called Atomic which is basically an `_Atomic_word` plus  methods that call the gcc atomic builtins.

```
class Atomic{
    mutable volatile _Atomic_word value_;
public:
    Atomic(int value = 0): value_(value) {}
    **** blah blah ****
};
```

I would like `std::numeric_limits<Atomic>` to instantiate to `std::numeric_limits<underlying integer type>` (e.g. on my system `_Atomic_word` is just a typedef for int).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<Atomic>` will instantiate with `Atomic` as the type, you can't subvert that. However you could specialise `std::numeric_limits` for `Atomic` like this

```
template<>
class numeric_limits< Atomic > : public numeric_limits< Atomic::UnderlyingType >
{
};
```

where you obviously expose `UnderlyingType` as a type in `Atomic`.